# Decent shared_ptr implementation that does not require a massive library?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am taking a C++ programming class right now on GIS Programming. I am really starting to get alot of headaches from dealing with proper memory management. Considering at any time there is often 8-10 classes each holding a pointer to a 3D matrix or something else very large. Now our class already raised the issue of the prof allowing us to use Boost, or atleast the C++ Feature Pack for 2008(for TR1). He refused but said if we wanted to we can find add a few third party cpp/hpp files. I already tried looking at getting shared_ptr out of boost but that is more of a headache than its worth.

So is there any sort of free shared_ptr implementation out there?

Comment: try asking him if you can use <tr1\memory> since it is part of gcc and then optionally include that in / swap out the vc feature pack.

the other pointers are good too, either using Loki or extracting it from boost.
you shouldn't have to worry about this.

Comment: Why not get you to write in C, so you really get a good lesson in how to torture yourself for no reason?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use boost's [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool. It will let you extract certain functionality from the boost libraries.

```
bcp shared_ptr /boost_shared_ptr
```

will extract shared_ptr and it's dependencies to that directory.

Answer (score 4):

Give [Lokis](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) ref-counted smart pointer a shot - as far as i recall its less coupled then boosts headers.

Answer (score 3):

Preprocess boost header that contains the definition of `shared_ptr`. Write it to a single .hpp file. This way you'll get boost `shared_ptr` and all its dependencies in one header file, without the need for full installation of boost.

`shared_ptr` does not need any shared library to be linked to your code, it is a header-only library... so this should work.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be a **terrible** idea for a production solution, it wouldn't be too hard to roll your own for a class, if you didn't try to be as cross compiler, flexible and thread safe as boost's:

```
template <typename contained>
class my_shared_ptr {
public:
   my_shared_ptr() : ptr_(NULL), ref_count_(NULL) { }

   my_shared_ptr(contained * p)
     : ptr_(p), ref_count_(p ? new int : NULL)
   { inc_ref(); }

   my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& rhs)
     : ptr_(rhs.p), ref_count_(rhs.ref_count_)
   { inc_ref(); }

   ~my_shared_ptr() {
     if(ref_count_ && 0 == dec_ref()) { delete ptr_; delete ref_count_; }
   }
   contained * get() { return ptr_; }
   const contained * get() const { return ptr_; }

   void swap(my_shared_ptr& rhs) // throw()
   {
      std::swap(p, rhs.p);
      std::swap(ref_count_, rhs.ref_count_);
   }

   my_shared_ptr& operator=(const my_shared_ptr& rhs) {
        my_shared_ptr tmp(rhs);
        this->swap(tmp);
        return *this;
   }

   // operator->, operator*, operator void*, use_count
private:
   void inc_ref() {
      if(ref_count_) { ++(*ref_count_); }
   }

   int  dec_ref() {
      return --(*ref_count_);
   }

   contained * ptr_;
   int * ref_count_;
};
```

Comment: some adjustments in your code :
my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& rhs)
    : ptr_(rhs.ptr_), ref_count_(rhs.ref_count_)
   { inc_ref(); }
and :
my_shared_ptr(contained * p)
     : ptr_(p), ref_count_(p ? new int(0) : NULL)
   { inc_ref(); }

Comment: "...and thread safe as boost". You have not audited Boost - there's nothing safe about it ;) I used Boost's `bcp` to pull out what I needed from Release 1.54.0 for `shared_ptr` and `regex` (so I should have gotten only what I needed). I looked at a few functions in `scoped_mutex` (linux) and `shared_mutex` (windows). Both are broken. The Boost library is clearly not ready for production (unless you think silent failures are a good thing), and its QA is an absolute joke (even compiler warnings, Clang scan-build, or Coverity's free service would have caught these mistakes).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <tr1/memory> // this is contained in STL.
std::tr1::shared_ptr<A> a = new A;
```

ow, just saw your professor doesnt allow you to use TR1. tough luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need shared ownership that much?

You can often get by with just a simple ad hoc RAII class, taking exclusive ownership of an object.

Memory management without RAII is a pain, but you an get RAII without `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

I just spotted a serious mistake in your code sample.
It should be

```
ref_count_(p ? new int(0) : NULL)
```

instead of

```
ref_count_(p ? new int : NULL)
```

the counter should be initialized to 0.
if not all your smart pointer is not smart anymore.
All those programmers that do those tiny mistake pay for it a lot in debugging later,
you should think like a compiler and act like it....